# FsXaml load error

Tags: .net, wpf, f#

I am trying to use FSXaml to create a gui in F#. I get the following error while compiling. I get the same error on the sample demo program from FsXaml as well. Thank you in advance for all the help.

The error I am getting is:

> FSC: error FS3031: The type provider
>   'C:\Dev\ATF\tp\FsXaml\Debug\FsXaml.Wpf.TypeProvider.dll' reported an
>   error: Assembly attribute 'TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute' refers to a
>   designer assembly 'FsXaml.Wpf.TypeProvider' which cannot be loaded or
>   doesn't exist. Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Dev\ATF\tp\FsXaml\Debug\FsXaml.Wpf.TypeProvider.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.

The full error is here:

> ------ Build started: Project: atfgui, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe -o:obj\Debug\atfgui.exe -g
>   --debug:full --noframework --define:DEBUG --define:TRACE --doc:bin\Debug\atfgui.XML --optimize- --tailcalls- --platform:x64 -r:C:\Dev\ATF\assembly\Debug\frameworkevents.dll -r:C:\Dev\ATF\tp\FsXaml\Debug\FsXaml.Wpf.dll -r:C:\Dev\ATF\tp\FsXaml\Debug\FsXaml.Wpf.TypeProvider.dll -r:C:\Dev\ATF\assembly\Debug\hostengine.dll -r:C:\Dev\ATF\assembly\Debug\mktdataservices.dll -r:C:\Dev\ATF\assembly\Debug\mktdatastructs.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll"
>   -r:C:\Dev\ATF\assembly\Debug\persistence.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\PresentationCore.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\PresentationFramework.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Numerics.dll"
>   -r:C:\Dev\ATF\tp\FsXaml\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xaml.dll"
>   -r:C:\Dev\ATF\assembly\Debug\tradingclasses.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\WindowsBase.dll"
>   --target:exe --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --validate-type-providers --LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors --subsystemversion:6.00 --highentropyva+ --sqmsessionguid:ed3396d7-c111-4f7c-91a2-bf3691c7001c "c:\temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.fs" atfgui.fs 
>   FSC: error FS3031: The type provider
>   'C:\Dev\ATF\tp\FsXaml\Debug\FsXaml.Wpf.TypeProvider.dll' reported an
>   error: Assembly attribute 'TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute' refers to a
>   designer assembly 'FsXaml.Wpf.TypeProvider' which cannot be loaded or
>   doesn't exist. Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Dev\ATF\tp\FsXaml\Debug\FsXaml.Wpf.TypeProvider.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format. FSC: warning FS3005: Referenced assembly
>   'C:\Dev\ATF\tp\FsXaml\Debug\FsXaml.Wpf.TypeProvider.dll' has assembly
>   level attribute
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute'
>   but no public type provider classes were found Done building project
>   "atfgui.fsproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: If you are using VS, it maybe easier to use a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was actually the CPU architecture of one of the components of FsXaml and FsXaml. I recompiled my code to be AnyCPU instead of X64 to be compatible with FsXaml, voila it worked.

Comment: I had very similar error (probably due to moving around project folders and editing *.fsproj file manually). The solution was to switch **Target F# runtime** in project properties from 4.3.0.0 to 4.3.1.0 — voila! it compiled, but could not load at runtime. Switching back to 4.3.0.0 restored everything to normal. Probably, VisualStudio just somehow 'cleaned up' my project file in the process.